# Creating button that displays different content when clicked

Tags: jquery, button, random, eventhandler

I am brand new to Jquery and web development and I am attempting to build a random quote generator.

The web app consists of one button that when clicked displays a new quote. It's a static site and its all done with html/css/jquery.

My problem is when the button is clicked it displays the first quote, but when clicked again it does not change. I want the button to show a new quote every time it is clicked.

I'm sure this is an easy fix for anyone proficient with Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quote-button").click(function() {
    $('#quote-box p').html(quotes[i].q);
    $('#quote-box a').attr('href', quotes[i].l);
    $('quote-box a').html(quotes[i].a);
  });
});

var quotes = [{
    q: 'The Great Man … is colder, harder, less hesitating, and without respect and  without the fear of “opinion”; he lacks the virtues that accompany respect and “respectability”, and altogether everything that is the “virtue of the herd”. If he cannot lead, he goes alone. … He knows he is incommunicable: he finds it tasteless to be familiar. … When not speaking to himself, he wears a mask. There is a solitude within him that is inaccessible to praise or blame. - Friedrich Nietzche, The Will to Power'
  }, {
    q: 'Power is given only to those who dare to lower themselves and pick it up. Only one thing matters, one thing; to be able to dare! Fyodor Dostoevsky'
  }, {
    p: 'The more sand has escaped from the hourglass of our life, the clearer we should see through it. Niccolo Machiavelli'
  }

];

var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at runtime, variable `i` is declared as a particular random number, so clicking it again would result show the exact same quote (since `i` doesn't change).

Put `var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));` within the `.click()` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your generated random numbers may be equal to previously generated random number, hence it will not get reflected. So you can check whether previous random is not equal to the new one, else generate a new random number. You can use the following code:

```
var new_random, old_random;
function random_num(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length));
}    

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".quote-button").click(function() {
        new_random = random_num(); //Generate a random number
        while(new_random == old_random){ // Check if previous and new are equal
            new_random = random_num();//if equal generate another
        }
        $('#quote-box p').html(quotes[new_random].q);
        $('#quote-box a').attr('href', quotes[new_random].l);
        $('quote-box a').html(quotes[new_random].a);
        old_random = new_random;
    });
});
```